# sprintf wrong result in some cases

Tags: php, text, format

I found some strange cases accidentally that are not working with `sprintf` php function. Anybody had the same issues or knows an explanation for it?

Here is the case that is not working:

```
$value = 1.15;
echo sprintf("%03d",($value*100));
```

If `$value` is defined by `1.15 * 2^n`, then the result always gonna be wrong.
If I run the function with another value, it's working well.

For correction, I used `strval` function like this:

```
echo sprintf("%03d",(strval($value*100)));
```

This way it works without any problems.

Somebody has an ideea what it's happening?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "%03f" or something?

Comment: Be specific - what do you mean by "result always gonna be wrong". What output do you get, for what input?

Comment: How  is the question different to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118247/php-sprintf-bug)? Are you two co-workers or something?

Comment: [Floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: Yes, we are co-workers. And by wrong i meant that instead of 115, the result will be 114. But we got the answer on the other post.